# How can I use empy Templates with conditional expansion?

Tags: python, templates, empy

I try to use **em.py**'s conditional to expand different, if a variable has a value:

```
import em

d1={"year":2012, "title":"abc"}
d2={"year":None, "title":"abc"}

p="@(year?year)@title" # the pattern
#p="@(year?year - )@title" # this does not work

print em.expand(p, d1)
print em.expand(p, d2)

# I would like to have it expanded into: "2012 - abc" for d1 and "abc" for d2
```

So, if the year is set (different from `None`), then the year should be inserted an a additional Separator (I use a dash with blanks around it:  " - ") should also be inserted.

**So: what pattern p should i use?**

I am aware that this works:

```
@(year?year)@(year?" - ")
```

but that is not as readable as I like it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a python expression using `and`:

```
@(year and str(year) + ' - ')
```

If `year` is `None`, it short-circuits and returns `None`, otherwise it returns `str(year) + ' - '`. You need to use `str(year)` because otherwise you'd be concatenating an `int` and a `str` type.